# Show/hide buttons based on a dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

Currently I have an aspx page that contains a dropdown list and four buttons. 
Based on the selection made in the dropdown list then a combination of the buttons are displayed.

I currently have this implemented so that when the user makes a selection I am using AutoPostBack and the selectedChanged server side event to determine which buttons to display and then set the Visible property of these buttons in this method.

Due to the fact that this posts back I don't think its a nice solution as the whole page is posting back. I would prefer to do this using JSON.

I made the following attempt but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            jQuery("#<%= MyDropdownList.ClientID %>").change(function () {
                 updateAvailableButtons(jQuery(this).val());
        });

    });

function updateAvailableButtons(selectedItemId) {
        jQuery("h2").html("selectedItemId:" + selectedItemId);
        jQuery.getJSON("MyPage.aspx/GetAvailableButtons?" + Id, function (data, textStatus) { debugger; });
    }
```

Server side:

```
protected void GetAvailableButtons(int selectedItemId)
    {
      //based on the id here then then I show hide certain buttons.
      button1.Visible = true;
      button2.Visible = false;
      button3.Visible = false;
      button4.Visible = false;
    }
```

I've never worked with JSON before so apologies if this is way off.

Comment: i think you mean jQuery not JSON

Comment: After you fetched json data from server, you must parse result data and show result to user. You must do this at the debugger line.

Answer (score 0):

Similar task can be done using JavaScript.  The problem is that you'll need to use a html  control instead of an asp.net button control so that you can manipulate form the client side.